# To find what percentage of the coin flips contains a streak of six heads or tails in a row?

Tags: python-3.x

I was doing practice problems from 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python' and I came across this question.
Write a program to find out how often a streak of six heads or a streak of six tails comes up in a randomly generated list of heads and tails.

1.the first part generates a list of randomly selected 'heads' and 'tails' values
2.the second part checks if there is a streak in it.

Put all of this code in a loop that repeats the experiment 10,000 times so we can find out what percentage of the coin flips contains a streak of six heads or tails in a row.

Here what i have done till now :

```
import random
myList = []
n = int(input('How many times do you want to toss the coin : '))
i = 0
while i <= n :
    outcome = random.randint(0,1)
    if outcome == 0 :
        toss = 'H'
        myList.append(toss)
    elif outcome == 1 :
        toss = 'T'
        myList.append(toss)
    i += 1

headStreak = 0
total_H_Streak = 0

for i in myList :
    if i == 'H' :
        headStreak += 1
        if headStreak == 6 :
            total_H_Streak += 1
    else :
        headStreak = 0
print('The streak of 6 heads in a row is : ',total_H_Streak)
tailStreak = 0
total_T_Streak = 0
for j in myList :
    if j == 'T' :
        tailStreak += 1
        if tailStreak == 6 :
            total_T_Streak += 1
    else :
        tailStreak = 0
print('The Streak of 6 tails in a row is : ',total_T_Streak)
```

Although I think this code is correct, I was wondering if there is any other approach to this problem.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: For starters, you can generate `myList` with `myList = random.choices('HT', k=n)`. However, this question is more suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: If you convert the results to a string, the streak check is as simple as `if 'TTTTTT' in results_string`. Of course the same goes for `'HHHHHH'`

Comment: "Although I think this code is correct" Did you test it?

Comment: @Mast Yeah, I have tested it with different values of n ranging from 1000 to 10000.

Answer (score 1):

An exact answer to the problem can be computed using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming); reframe the problem from calculating the probability, into counting the number of sequences of length `n` which don't contain any streak of `k` in a row. The probability of getting no streaks of length `k` or more is that number divided by `2**n`; of course, if you want the probability of getting at least one streak, you can subtract that result from 1. This gives an exact probability (subject to floating point precision), rather than an estimate by sampling.

The algorithm works by maintaining a "state" which is a list of the current number of sequences ending with a streak of length `r`, where `r` is the index in the list, ranging from 0 to `k - 1` where `k` is the forbidden streak length. To update the state, each current streak can either be broken by a "different" flip, resulting in a new streak of length 1, or it can be continued by a "same" flip, resulting in a new streak of length `r + 1`. We should only count "continued" streaks if the resulting streak length is less than `k`. The initial state has a single streak of length 0, because no flips have been made yet.

Here's an implementation:

```py
def probability_of_no_runs(n, k):
    state = [1] + [0] * (k-1)

    for i in range(n):
        new_state = [0] * k
        for r, c in enumerate(state):
            new_state[1] += c
            if r < k - 1:
                new_state[r + 1] += c
        state = new_state

    return sum(state) / 2**n
```

Example:

```py
>>> probability_of_no_runs(10, 3)
0.173828125
>>> probability_of_no_runs(100, 6)
0.19317945128367534
>>> probability_of_no_runs(100, 10)
0.9133409556516383
```

By viewing the state transition as a linear transformation, it's possible to improve on this algorithm by writing the whole thing as a matrix product `A**n * s` where `A` is the transition matrix and `s` is the initial state. This could be more efficient because the [matrix power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) can be computed in `log n` steps instead of `n` steps as this loop uses.

The algorithm above could also be adapted to count the distribution of how many streaks occur; in that case, the state should be a two-dimensional grid where one index is the current streak length and the other index is the number of streaks so far. You would need to decide what to do about overlapping streaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#first part: generates a list of random H/T.
import random

streak = 0
repeat = 0

while repeat < 10000:
    flips = []

    #Generates a random list of H or T with 100 items.
    for i in range(100):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            flips.append('H')
        else:
            flips.append('T')

    #print(flips, end='\n\n')

    # Find a streak of 6 of either H or T.
    for i in range(len(flips)):
        count = 0
        for x in range(6):
            try: # at item 95, Python will report error Index out of range which can be ignored.
                if flips[i] == flips[i + x]:
                    count += 1
                else:
                    break
            except IndexError:
                break

        if count == 6:
            streak += 1
            #print("Found a streak!")

    repeat += 1

print("Repeats: " + str(repeat))
print("Streaks: " + str(streak))
print("flips: " + str(repeat * 100))
print("The odds are " + str((streak / (10000 * 100 / 100))) + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually used only one "for loop" counting and updating all the things needed within every loop and assuming that 0 is head and 1 is tail.
Here it is how:

```
import random

# Head = 0 - Tail = 1

# Vars
head_count = 0
tail_count = 0
head_streaks = 0
tail_streaks = 0

# If head or tail, add 1 to the side counter. If it gets to 6, add 1 to the streake counter and reset the side counter
for i in range(10000):
    rand = random.randint(0,1)
    if rand == 0:
        head_count +=1
        if head_count == 6:
            head_streaks +=1
        # Every time a side happens, the opposite side count is set to 0
        tail_count = 0
    else:
        tail_count +=1
        if tail_count == 6:
            tail_streaks +=1
        head_count = 0

print("Head odds: ", str(head_streaks/10000), "%")
print("tail odds: ", str(tail_streaks/10000), "%")
```

Answer (score 1):

While I was solving practice problems from the book Automate the boring stuff with Python, I came across this problem. Write a program to find out how often a streak of six heads or a streak of six tails comes up in a randomly generated list of heads and tails.

The approach that I took, comprised of breaking down the problem into two sub-parts, the first part generates a list of randomly selected 'heads' and 'tails' values, and the second part checks if there is a streak in it. Put all of this code in a loop that repeats the experiment 10,000 times so we can find out what percentage of the coin flips contains a streak of six heads or tails in a row.

Here is what I have done till now:

```
import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
for experimentNumber in range(10000):
    # Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    experimentOutcomes =[]
    for i in range(100):
        if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            experimentOutcomes.append('H')
        else:
            experimentOutcomes.append('T')

    #print(experimentOutcomes)



    # Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
    for i in range(len(experimentOutcomes)):
        count = 0
        for j in range(6):
            try: # at item 95, Python will report error Index out of range which can be ignored.
                if experimentOutcomes[i] == experimentOutcomes[i+j]:
                    count += 1
                else:
                    break
            except IndexError:
                break


        if count == 6:
            numberOfStreaks += 1



print('The percentage of the coin flips that contain a streak of six heads or tails in a row: ' + str((numberOfStreaks / (10000*95))*100) +'%')
```

How did I calculate the percentage?
For an experiment of tossing a coin 100 times in a row, there are 95 such possible streaks of 6. For 10000 times the experiment was repeated, multiply 10000 with 95. So these are the total possible outcomes of a streak of length 6. So, we divide the actual outcomes with the number of possible outcomes to find the probability.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of the question was working on lists.  Below is my solution.  Keep in mind, the odds of it happening at any one point in time are:

(1/2)*(1/2)*(1/2)*(1/2)*(1/2)*(1/2) or (1/2)^6, so your sample set answer should be around 1.56%

NOTE:  the try / except block was just to handle the issue of the index + x running out of actual index numbers towards the end of the list.

```
import random
streak = 0
number_of_100_flips = 10000
for num in range(number_of_100_flips):
    coin_flip = []
    #flip 100 times
    for val in range(101):
        toss = random.randint(0,1)
        if toss == 0:
            coin_flip.append('H')
        else:
            coin_flip.append('T')

    for i in range(len(coin_flip)+1):
        counter = 0
        try:
            for x in range(1,7):
                if coin_flip[i] == coin_flip[i+x]:
                    counter += 1
                if counter == 6:
                    streak += 1
                    counter = 0
        except:
            pass       
print('A streak of 6 in a row during 100 flips occured {:.2%} of the time.'.format(streak/(100*number_of_100_flips), number_of_100_flips))
print(f'The experiment was done {number_of_100_flips} times')
```

Comment: You're the only person I've seen mention what the probability SHOULD be which is really the heart of the problem. The difference between probability and frequency. The FREQUENCY is what the program calculates (say something like 0.015596). The probability is (1/2)^6 or an ESTIMATE of what the actual frequency will be upon testing. You mention ODDs. This is something different. An odd is a ratio of two probabilities. The odds of it happening are dimensionless. They would be Pr(streak)/Pr(!Streak) which may be very close to .015625 but they aren't actually the same thing.

Comment: This is correct.  What you are describing is a bit above my understanding off odds.   What i mean to convey with that the sample set should be close to the expected outcome of 1.5%.   Each sample could be higher or lower because of the specific sample set.  But if you are consistently getting 10% or higher then you have likely coded the logic wrong based of the number of standard deviations needed to get there.

Comment: The probability of getting six in a row is indeed ~1.56%. The question states "...so we can find out what percentage of the coin flips contains a streak of six heads or tails in a row.". 

I interpreted this, probably incorrectly, as meaning calculate the total number of flips that could occur, i.e. 100/6 = 16 remainder 4. Then calculate the number that did occur, which is say 1 or 2 and then find the ratio (1/16) which is about 6.25%.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of people using for loops to calculate the streak of six in their lists. Whilst the question asks you to create a list of outcomes, you can actually just then convert the list to a string and then use the .count() method to identify the number of occurrences:

```
import random

#Produce list of 100 flips
outcomes = []

for ii in range(100):
    rand = random.randint(0,1)
    if rand == 0:
        outcomes.append('T')
    else:
        outcomes.append('H')

#Count number of streaks
outcomes_string = ''.join(outcomes)
tail_streak = outcomes_string.count('T'*6)
head_streak = outcomes_string.count('H'*6)

streaks = tail_streak + head_streak
print(streaks)

#Calculate percentage
#add your code here
```

The previous question in the book actually asks you to write a piece of code that can print any list into a specified string format as well.

Obviously you modify the code accordingly so it runs the experiment 10000 times.

Answer (score 1):

New to both programming and StackOverflow, so please bear with me if my formatting isn't correct, but I figured this one out. I think that the question is correctly interpreted as case #1 on this guy's Quora post wherein any set of 100 flips which contains at least 6 consecutive heads or tails is considered a streak:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-probability-in-percent-of-getting-six-heads-in-a-row-or-six-tails-in-a-row-if-you-flip-a-coin-100-times-this-is-not-a-homework-problem

Therefore, the probability should be around 0.8. The following code gives this probability:

```
import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
for experimentNumber in range(10000):
    #Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    list=[]
    for flip in range(100):
    value=random.randint(0,1)
    if value == 0:
        value = 'heads'
    else:
        value = 'tails'
    list.append(value)
#Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
streak=1 # No matter which value we start on, we can consider it to be the first of a potential streak of 6
for i in range(len(list)):
    if i==0:
        pass
    elif list[i]==list[i-1]:
        streak+=1 # Reset back to the first of a potential streak of 6 if it doesn't work out
    else:
        streak=1
    if streak>=6: # Include streaks of more than 6 consecutive identical results
        numberOfStreaks+=1
        break
print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numberOfStreaks / 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
result = []
for i in range(100):
    if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
        value = 'H'
    else:
        value = 'T'
    result.append(value)
streaks = 1
for i in range(len(result)):
    try:

        if result[i] == result[i+1]:
            streaks += 1
        else:
            streaks = 1
        if streaks == 6:
            numberOfStreaks +=1
            streaks = 0
    except IndexError:
        print('done')

print(result)
print(numberOfStreaks)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep it simple( from what I know of, I'm learning).
I noted everything to break it down easier.

```
import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
H = 0 # Tracks number of times H in a row.
T = 0 # Tracks number of times T in a row.
for experimentNumber in range(10000):   
     r= (random.randint(0, 1))
     if r == 0:
        print('H')
        H = H + 1 # Adds to number of H in a row
            T = 0 # resets T to 0 when H is produced
        if H == 6: # Checks for streak
            numberOfStreaks= numberOfStreaks + 1
            H = 0 # sets H back to 0 after streak acheived
    elif r == 1:
        print('T')
        T = T + 1
        H = 0
        if T == 6:
            numberOfStreaks = numberOfStreaks + 1
            T = 0
    
    # code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
 print(' Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numberOfStreaks / 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(number):
    if number > 1:
        return number * factorial(number - 1)
    else:
        return 1

'''
   Using combinations:
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination
'''
def combinations(k, n):
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n-k))

'''
   Using Bernulli's formula
'''
def Bernulli_scheme(k, n):
    return combinations(k, n) * (0.5 ** k) * (0.5 ** (n-k))

print(Bernulli_scheme(6,100))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

heads = 0
tails = 0
streak = 0
lister = []
for x in range(10001):
    for x in range(101):
        x = random.randint(0,1)
        if x == 0:
            heads = heads + 1
            lister.append('H')
            print(lister)
        if x == 1:
            tails = tails + 1
            lister.append('T')
            print(lister)  
            for l in range(len(lister)):
                if tails == 6 or heads == 6:
                    streak += 1
            break
    print('Probability: %s%% streak' %(streak/100))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solution using one loop:

```
#Heads and Tails

import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
coinFlips = []

for __ in range(10000): # number of experiments

    # Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    coinFlips = random.choices('HT', k=100)
    
    # Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
    numberOfStreaks += ('T'*6 in ''.join(coinFlips)) or ('H'*6 in ''.join(coinFlips))

print('Chance of a streak = :%s%%' %(numberOfStreaks /100))
```